# Connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 from Windows 98

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 from a Windows 98 machine?

If it is possible, what would I use?

I have an old testing machine that currently writes to an access database.  This testing machine is probably finally going to be replaced in a year or 2.

I want to migrate the Access database to SQL Server, but as part of that effort I'd need to be able to have the Windows 98 machine write to the SQL Server.

It takes about 6 months or so to build a replacement piece of test equipment, and lately we've hit some pretty serious growth in our business, so even with all the test equipment we have, we still run behind. So it will be 2 more pieces before we can replace it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per a comment from [David Browne](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/126936/david-browne-microsoft), you should try using the built-in SQL Server ODBC driver.

One approach for doing this is to connect to SQL Server *through* MS Access with [Linked Tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-linked-tables-1d9346d6-953d-4f85-a9ce-4caec2262797).